# How does the function return something without return statement?

Tags: c, gcc

It works in the Windows Command Prompt like I haven't missed the `return new_node;`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
 } Node;

Node* create_node(int value) {
    Node *new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) return NULL;
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    // no return statement
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Node *head = NULL;

    // no errors here, head just receives the right pointer
    head = create_node(5);

    return 0;
}
```

So the function `create_node(int)` returns pointer anyway. How does it work?

Compiled with gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.2.0

Comment: It's undefined behavior. It just looks like it is returning something. Accidentally.

Comment: That is because you did not enable warnings of your compiler: it would have warned you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's undefined behavior and standard mentions it clearly

From §6.9.1¶12 C11 standard

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Compile your code with all warnings enabled. `gcc -Wall -Werror prog.c`. In this case you will see compiler mentioning that there is no return statement though it is supposed to return something.